# R: find people had glucose tests at least 4 times a month and continued for at least 2 months

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(PATIENT_ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
             test.year=c(2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001),
             test.month=c(1,1,1,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
             value=c(3.4,3.2,3.5, 3.9, 1.2, 2.1, 2.9, 2.7, 4.6,5.6,5.9,4.2,4.4,6.1,9.4))
```

I have a dataset which contains glucose test time (calendar year and calendar month) and values for patients. I want to find the patients who had glucose tests at least 4 times a month and continued for at least 2 months, and return the row with the earliest test time and value, using R.

The expected output is:

```
    df <- data.frame(PATIENT_ID=c(2),
             test.year=c(2001),
             test.month=c(1),
             value=c(2.7))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with `dplyr`. I group by patient and test month to count how many tests a patient had per month. Then I calculate the difference in months between tests per patient, taking care of the year issue. I then filter for patients that had at least two consecutive tests over 2 months (so `month_diff` == 1) and had at least 4 tests per month. Then I only keep the first test point and drop the now unused variables `month_dif` and `n`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(PATIENT_ID, test.month) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>% 
  mutate(month_dif = case_when(test.year == lag(test.year) ~ test.month - lag(test.month),
                               test.year - lag(test.year) == 1 & test.month == 1 & lag(test.month) == 12 ~ 1,
                               TRUE ~ NA_real_)) %>% 
  filter(any(month_dif == 1) & n >= 4) %>% 
  slice_head(1) %>% 
  select(-month_dif, - n)

# A tibble: 1 x 4
# Groups:   PATIENT_ID [1]
  PATIENT_ID test.year test.month value
       <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
1          2      2001          1   2.7
```

This updated solution also takes care of the year issue mentioned by @Gal.

**Data with two consecutive measurement points occuring not in the same year**

```
df <- data.frame(PATIENT_ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                 test.year=c(2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2002),
                 test.month=c(1,1,1,3,3,3,3,12,12,12,12,1,1,1,1),
                 value=c(3.4,3.2,3.5, 3.9, 1.2, 2.1, 2.9, 2.7, 4.6,5.6,5.9,4.2,4.4,6.1,9.4))
```

Comment: You should also consider the year?

Comment: I copied your codes but got: Error in slice_head(., 1).

Comment: Good point, but not entirely clear from the question. Could also be that `test.month` is one for the first month the patient tests, irrespective of calendar month and then year would not matter. I now noted this in my answer.

Comment: @Franky `slice_head` is part of the latest `dplyr` release. Update `dplyr` then it should work

Comment: the test.month is the calendar month. December is 12, and January is 1.

Comment: @Franky I just updated my answer. Now it should work with calendar months

Comment: @Dominik S. Meier Can I ask what do "filter(any(month_dif == 1)" and "select(-month_dif, - n)" mean? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Filter keeps only patients that had tests in two consecutive months (so month_dif = 1) and the select statements drops those two unused variables. I updated my answer to provide an explanation.

Comment: @Dominik S. Meier Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution in Base-R. I made a custom function to filter to avoid stacking `splits` with `unlists`

```
multifilter <- function(data,filterorder){  
  newdata <- list(data)
  for(i in rev(filterorder)){
    newdata <- unlist(lapply(sort(unique(data[,i])), function(x) lapply(newdata, function(y) y[y[,i]==x,])),recursive=F)
  }
  return(newdata[sapply(newdata,nrow)>=1])
}

df_new <- multifilter(df, c("PATIENT_ID","test.year"))
df_new <- do.call(rbind,lapply(df_new, function(x) ifelse(sum(table(x$test.month)>3)>1,return(x[1,]),NA)))
df_new <- df_new[complete.cases(df_new),]
```

output:

```
> df_new
  PATIENT_ID test.year test.month value
8          2      2001          1   2.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
ntimes <- 4L
nmths <- 2L

               #aggregate number of tests per month
ix <- setDT(df)[, .(.N, rn=.I[1L]), .(PATIENT_ID, mths=test.year*12L + test.month)][
    #filter for at least 4 times, and create a grouping variable that identify consecutive months
    N >= ntimes, .(rn, g=cumsum(c(0L, diff(mths)!=1L))), .(PATIENT_ID)][,
        #filter for those with at least 2 months and get the first row of the same grouping
        if (.N >= nmths) rn[1L], .(PATIENT_ID, g)]$V1
df[ix]
```

output:

```
   PATIENT_ID test.year test.month value
1:          2      2001          1   2.7
```